# who are other than oracle who have implemented JVM spec ? Is there other JRE/JDK than from Oracle?

Tags: java

As JVM is only specification -

who are other software product companies who have implemented their own JVM ?

How many different implementations are done by Oracle for JVM ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29

Comment: The OpenJDK is the reference implementation for the JVM.

Comment: Downvoted as showing no effort on the part of the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of them. IBM's is probably the most used outside of Oracle's.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Comment: Yap, IBM JRE is used by WebSphere Application Server, so it is pretty wide-spread.

Answer (score 2):

List of Java Virtual Machine in wikipedia

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

I would suggest to have a look to OpenJDK http://openjdk.java.net/